# How to solve optimistic concurrency update case in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

Is there any way to know when optimistic concurrency problem occurs in JPA and how to solve it?

**Problem description:**
In my project, when I want to update data in DB but other user was using it. At that kind of situation, I want to get DB_STATUS or exception which means "Other user was using..". So that I want to skip updating DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Version` field or property is used by the persistence provider to perform optimistic locking. It is accessed and/or set by the persistence provider in the course of performing lifecycle operations on the entity instance. An entity is automatically enabled for optimistic locking if it has a property or field mapped with a `Version mapping`:

Define a `version` property in your entity:

```
@Version
private long version;
```

and a corresponding `version` field in your DB table for the entity.

Suppose you have loaded an entity having id=123 and version=1. Once transaction gets completed, the entity state will change into `detached` state.

You made changes to the entity in its `detached` state. You can make these changes persistent using `EntityManager.merge()`. And as it is a `detached` instance, Hibernate will issue an SQL update similar to this:

```
update ENTITY set ... , VERSION=2 where ID=123 and VERSION=1
```

If another application transaction would have updated the same ENTITY since it was loaded, the VERSION column would not contain the value 1, and the row would not be updated. You will receive a `OptimisticLockException` and the transaction will be marked for rollback. You can catch the exception and inform the User about the stale data.

The merge operation examines the `version` attribute when an entity is being merged and throws an `OptimisticLockException` if it is discovered that the object being merged is a stale copy of the entity—i.e. that the entity has been updated since the entity became detached.